# Allowing user to change the text of a div

Tags: javascript, html

This was just a query in another of my questions. However i got no solution so i am reposting this question and hopefully someone can solve my dilemma.

I have a div.I want the div contents to be editabe.
what i basically want is onlick of a button the div should turn into a text box and allow the user to change the contents of the div. I would prefer to avoid Jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/qbXcw/11/

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="allowedit">CLICK BUTTON TO EDIT THIS TEXT
        <input type="button" value="CLK ME" onclick="changetext(this)" />
    </div>
  <div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
changetext = function (e) {  
     src=(e.parentNode);
     src.outerHTML="<div><input +"+"name=input"+"></div>";     
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to save the text until edited?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use html attribute [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable)

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

Comment: This will probably not work in older browsers. For your info.

Comment: I need it only on IE8 and above , SO i guess this will be my solution... also since this a property i can add a clause allowing the div to be editable conditinally. PERFECT

Comment: @Kevin I thought same, but then saw this :) Internet Explorer 5.5+ (see mdn link in question for browser compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="allowedit" contenteditable="true">
  CLICK BUTTON TO EDIT THIS TEXT        
 </div>
```